# Process performance over SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a time-consuming process that iterates a collection of items (e.g. 3500), where I need to query a database (currently using SQL Server) for each item (in fact very simple query).

I'm doing the queries one by one (in the loop) instead of an only batch query at the beggining, because the DAO has been given and I'm not able to change it at this moment.

The problem that I'm facing is that, if this process takes 2 minutes, 1'55" of them belongs to database accesses ... and "only" 5" for the hard work. I'm creating an only connection (at the beginning) instead of creating 3500 connections (too much payload), and also I tried to create a transaction at the beginning ... but it takes the same.

My question is: Is there any way to improve the performance of those queries, one by one, without reimplementing the DAL in order to do a batch query?

Attaching a pic of the SQL Server profiler:

[image: SQL Server profiler pic]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the query? And why do you query the DB for each collection item? It would be much simpler (and 3499 times more efficient) to send just one query through which would return the count for all collection items (I'm assuming that's what you're doing with your query).

Comment: This probably needs better tags too. I removed profiler since that's not the correct one for SQL Server profiler -- and really the problem isn't caused by profiler

Comment: What's the source for the collection? If it's also Sql Server, you likely need to just write a JOIN query and get this all down to one SQL statement.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu yes, at the end I was able to force a change in the data access layer, so that I can now perform an only query to retrieve the 3500 results at a time (the query takes 0.02 s :)). Once it's done, the loop is as fast as I wanted because, for every item, now an only access to a in-memory dictionary is performed :)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

The duration of those queries is ~0ms. You cannot improve this, no matter what the query is.

You should find out why 3500 0ms queries take 2min. That is far too long. Maybe the time is spent elsewhere or on the network.

Comment: exactly, that was my biggest concern (why are they taking too much if every individual query is so fast?). I'm working in a LAN network, so this should not be the reason ... maybe the server is overloaded or something like that. As I said in my previous comment, I finally managed to perform an only query to retrieve all the data, so that the process is now fine. Thanks!

Comment: "this process takes 2 minutes, 1'55" of them belongs to database accesses" Why are you saying this and misleading answerers if you yourself know that this cannot be true? Your problem is solved now, but we could have investigated by profiling the app.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I know that because I put timers in order to know what part of the process belongs to my memory structures, and what other part of the process belongs to DAL activity ...